# Can't seem to change properties of objects in winforms C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

This is a bit of a confusing scenario. Basically, I'm trying to set a button's color when I use setter for a private variable that I store its color in.

First off, I have a seperate window for customizing stuff. When I change the button color, I want to change every button in this window as well. I have it stored in a static variable in my main form class.

```
public static frm_custom customizer;
```

This is the setter for the variable in question.

```
private Color _buttonColor;
public Color buttonColor
{
    get { return this._buttonColor; }
    set
    {
        this.btn_input.BackColor = buttonColor;
        this._buttonColor = buttonColor;
        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_custom>().Count() == 1)
        {
            customizer.setButtonColor(buttonColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Strangely, it doesn't effect the color at all. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you show the actual code? The above code won't compile. You can't put an `if` statement floating around after the `set` block in a property.

Comment: He just has bad braces.

Comment: @Trey: That's what would stop it from *compiling*. But it's not all that's wrong with the code.

Comment: Well. yes and no, he is setting the color after he sets the property backer, so it does nothing, plus the code to set it is not inside the braces of the set...

Comment: The braces were a mistake when I posted it here. fixed it.

Comment: @JonSkeet He was just calming me down about the syntax, that's all.

Comment: @RamaRaunt Thanks for the fix. It's an unfortunate fact here that if you include one small typo like that in your question, folks like me will often instantly develop a laser-like obsession with it and be weirdly unable to even contemplate whatever your actual problem is. The train's fine, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Did I do something wrong?

Yes. Your setter is just fetching the *existing* property value:

```
this.btn_input.BackColor = buttonColor;
this._buttonColor = buttonColor;
```

You meant to use `value`, which is the implicit parameter name for the setter:

```
this.btn_input.BackColor = value;
this._buttonColor = value;
```

(Ditto for your `if` block, but it's hard to tell how that's meant to work as it's not valid C# at the moment.)

As a side note, I'd *strongly* urge you to start following .NET naming conventions, which include capital letters for properties - so `ButtonColor` rather than `buttonColor`.

Comment: @RamaRaunt If this answer has resolved your issue, please accept it.